# Access repository in foreach

Tags: c#, foreach, repository

I am wondering about what is best in performance terms. Access a repository instantiated yet in each foreach iteration, or get all data in a list and manage it after. In service layer I refer.

Also, is it a bad practice to access a repo in each loop iteration?

For example:

```
foreach(Task task in tasks)
{
  var data = taskRepo.GetSomeData(task);
  task.ThingsResult = otherRepo.DoThings(data);
}
```

Comment: What is your repository? Is it an DB-abstraction? Is it initiate access to DB each time called or have any cache mechanisms?

Comment: What is best in performance terms is to *measure*. If the performance is an issue then look at alternatives, measuring each.

Comment: My repository is based in Entity Framework and a Oracle DB. Each repo call goes to DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get all data and process it once it has been retrieved if you're absolutely sure you're going to need *all data*.
2. Get data in each iteration if you are accessing paged data or not all data each time. If you're getting the same data all over again, this is a waste of time and resources which negatively impacts performance. Go to first case if this is the case...

Comment: Is the first case. Thanks!